# Sendgrid api loading csv file

Tags: php, json, csv, sendgrid

this is causing me a headache...
I am trying to load a csv file in to a list on sendgrid and it is not working, I have spent hours looking and trying different things, below are my versions of code that have different degrees of success:

```
$file_handle = fopen("examplecsv.csv", "r");
$listname = "examplelist";
$url = 'https://sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/add.json?api_user='.$username.'&api_key='.$password; 
$str= '&list=' . $listname;  

$array = array();
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
  $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
  $str.= '&data[]={"email":"'.$line_of_text[0] . '"}';
}

return file_get_contents($url.$str);

fclose($file_handle);
extract($_POST);
```

or

```
$file_handle = fopen("examplecsv.csv", "r");

 $array = array();
 while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

 $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
 $array[] = 'email":"'.$line_of_text[0];

}
 $emails = json_encode($array);
 $emails = str_replace("\\", '', $emails);

 fclose($file_handle);
 extract($_POST);

//set POST variables
 $url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/add.xml';
 $fields = array(
                    'api_user' => 'username',
                    'api_key' => 'password',
                    'list' => 'example list',
                    'data' => '{$emails}'
            );

//url-ify the data for the POST
 foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
 rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
 $ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
 $result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
 curl_close($ch);
```

The second version is causing a non valid json string.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In your **first sample** you're not providing SendGrid all the required data. You're also doing it as a `GET` request, *which can cause its own problems*.

The email addition endpoint *requires* a name parameter be provided in the JSON string.

The difficulty you're having with your **second sample** appears to be from trying to create JSON objects using strings and *then* `json_encode` those strings. *However, the largest issue looks to be that you're providing the wrong type of array.*

The code looks like it's attempting to do:

```
data=[{"email" => "nick@sendgrid.com"},{"email" => "jane@example.com"}]
```

While SendGrid expects

```
data[]={"email" => "nick@sendgrid.com"}&data[]={"email" => "jane@example.com"}
```

## The Fix

*The following code should work for most versions of PHP.* It addresses both errors and sends SendGrid the format it expects.

```
$emails = array();

$file_handle = fopen("examplecsv.csv", "r");
// Iterate through the csv taking out the emails
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    // You can set "name" to be anything, however null works just as well.
    $field = array( "email" => $line_of_text[0], "name" => null);
    $emails[] = json_encode($field);
}

fclose($file_handle);

print_r($emails);

//set POST variables
$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/add.xml';
$fields = array(
    'api_user' => 'username',
    'api_key' => 'password',
    'list' => 'example list',
    'data' => $emails
);

$query = http_build_query($fields);

// Change data parameters to what SendGrid wants
$query = preg_replace("/data%5B\d+%5D/","data[]", $query);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);
```

**EDIT**: Changed the answer to correct the error introduced in prior answer (noted in comments).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand what you mean, you have explained it very clearly. I have tried your code but I keep getting 'A database error has occured. Please try again' error, any ideas why that might be?

Comment: I dunno if it's still relevant, but I determined the error, and corrected the answer.

Comment: @NickQ. Your code worked perfectly. past one day, i was trying to create such format. I got it.